# I need help with my steam account recovery

Tags: steam

I forgot my password, and when I clicked I can't sign in. And when I entered my name, and everything, it says that it is going to send the verification code to this email that I is not mine, I even checked if I entered the correct user name, and it was correct. Is there anything I can do? Am I hacked?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you asked the same question and that one got closed.
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363219/my-steam-account-email-is-incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact Steam support directly in order to recover your account.

Follow the instructions in the [steam account recovery guide](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2347-qdfn-4366).

You will need proof of ownership, this can be for example one of the payment methods that were used to purchase games on the account. 
A full list is in the linked guide.

Also make a list of any previous account names and related email addresses that were registered to the account, all of that will help you get the account back.

Good luck.

PS: In the future you should consider adding extra security to your account, for example two factor authentication with [steam guard](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4020-ALZM-5519) on your cellphone.